# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider') in Firebase on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, undefined

I am developping Firebase Cloud Messaging to my Android from NodeJS server.

Receiving notifications from the FCM console page was successful.

And I implemented server code with FCM Docs. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

But at runtime I get an error :

```
[0] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')
[0]     at Object._getProvider (/Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.cjs.js:274:26)
[0]     at getMessagingInSw (/Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/index.sw.cjs:1522:16)
[0]     at sendPushNotification (/Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/server/routes/product.js:86:5)
[0]     at /Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/server/routes/product.js:54:9
[0]     at /Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4616:16
[0]     at /Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:264:16
[0]     at model.<anonymous> (/Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:472:7)
[0]     at /Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/kareem/index.js:315:21
[0]     at next (/Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/kareem/index.js:209:27)
[0]     at /Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/kareem/index.js:182:9
[0]     at /Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/kareem/index.js:507:38
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
[0] Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
[0]     at /Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4618:13
[0]     at /Users/scmoon/Desktop/work/CheckRefrigerator/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:264:16
[0]     [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

There is no 'getProvider' in my code.

I did googling and tried alternative codes

but it still not working.

here is my code.

```
...
// const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
// const fbapp = initializeApp();

//const { getMessaging } = require("firebase/messaging");
const { getMessaging } = require("firebase/messaging/sw");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require('../../server/firebase-adminsdk-asdf.json');
const fbapp = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const registrationTokens = [
    'ePBbqfWEQ7yaj5Zjxera98...',
    // …
];

const message = {
    notification: { title: req_body.writer, body: req_body.title },
    tokens: registrationTokens,
};

getMessaging(fbapp)
    // .sendMulticast(message)
    .sendAll([message])
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.successCount + ' messages were sent successfully');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a firebase expert but it seems that sendAll messages expect a `token` property without a `s` while sendMulticast accepts `tokens`.
Which actually makes sense after reading the docs:

- `token` to send each message to 1 target
- `tokens` to send each message to n targets